# Getting ADB to run

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk

I've recently installed ubuntu and I need Android SDK (and subsequently, adb) in order to develop my apps to college. The fact is that, no matter what I do, I can't get adb to work. Exporting its place to the PATH didn't worked. I only get "file or directory not found" error while this are the contents of the PATH variable:

```
renan@RocketQueen:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/renan/adt/sdk/tools:/home/renan/adt/sdk/platform-tools
```

I don't want to install android-tools-adb/fastboot because they're outdate when compared to SDK Manager ones. What do I need to do in order for it to work from anywhere when called from terminal?

Comment: If `adb` is at `/home/renan/adt/sdk/platform-tools` and your exported path is the one above, then it should run by just typing `adb` in the terminal

Comment: the matter is that adb is there, but I still get the file not found error

Comment: If you really want just a quick solution, make a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/adb` of the adb executable

Comment: gave me the same error. do I need to remove the exported path first?

`renan@RocketQueen:~$ sudo ln -s /home/renan/adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
[sudo] password for renan: 
renan@RocketQueen:~$ adb
bash: /usr/bin/adb: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
renan@RocketQueen:~$`

Comment: Is your platform 32-bit or 64-bit? What is the output of `ldd $(which adb)`

Comment: 64bit. The command didn't ran, it gave me an error.

Comment: 64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html  see below

Comment: if you don't have libc6:i386, libncurses5:i386, and libstdc++6:i386 installed you will receive the "file not found" error . . . http://www.gaggl.com/2014/05/android-sdk-issues-on-ubuntu-14_04_64bit/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
cd /home/renan/adt/sdk/platform-tools
./adb
```

if you get an error you may need to run

```
sudo ./adb
```

instead

Source:

http://www.gaggl.com/2014/05/android-sdk-issues-on-ubuntu-14_04_64bit/

For full multiarch support you can run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(after adding the i386 arch and running apt-get update of course)

http://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/

Comment: managed to fix it by following this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16310606, but I'll try this one you told me too. Thanks!